# Unable to find package {3rd Party Package}. No packages exist with this id in source(s)

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd

I'm currently working on the project that has an Azure Artifact, specifically nuget packages,
and I'm using DotNetCoreCLI@2 for the dotnet restore and build, for the dotnet restore it is a success but for the build it always failed. Please see screenshot below. I don't know why it fails.

I've also included the vstsFeed in the build stage however still failing.

[image: Error]

and this is my yaml file

[image: YML file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing some key concepts of a multi-stage pipeline:

- **Stages** are a good way of thinking of your entire continuous-delivery process, eg BUILD -> DEV -> TEST -> PROD. Some teams use *stages* to represent *environments*. Stages run in sequence or in parallel and can have dependencies between them to control their order. Stages must contain at least one or more jobs. If you had approval gates applied, approvals are required for the entire *stage*.
- **Jobs** are often used to group large related activities together, like construction of a build artifact that will used in subsequent stages, deploying into an environment, running an automated regression suite, performing a security scan, etc. Jobs are comprised of at least one or more steps. The main advantage to having multiple jobs in a single stage is useful for parallelism, or re-running all jobs in the stage or just the failing ones.
- **Steps** are the individual activities within a job.

The key thing you're missing here is unless you are running in a self-hosted build-agent pool with only one build agent, each "job" *runs on a different machine*. So performing a restore on one machine and then compiling on another machine will always fail.

The process you want:

1. NuGetAuthenticate. This creates a nuget.config on the build agent that points to the vstsFeed
2. DotNet Restore. This pulls the packages from the vsts feed to the build agent so that the solution has all the dependencies it needs to compile.
3. DotNet Build. Compile the project file using the dependencies.

```yaml
- stages: "BUILD"
  job: "BUILD"
  steps:

  - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
    displayName: 'Setup NuGet to use Azure Artifacts'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      vstsFeed: '<<GUID>>'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Compile'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
```

Next, add some tests, code scanning and then publish a 'build artifact' that can be downloaded at the start of the next stage.